# Disable menu items on ApplescriptObjc

Tags: cocoa, menuitem, applescript-objc

I am coding with ApplescriptObjc.
I want to disable a menu item "Preference..." in a function, but I can't do it.

I can disable buttons. Here is the code:

```
myButton's setEnabled_(false)
```

So I tried to disable a menu item like a button:

```
myMenuItem's setEnabled_(false)
```

I looked at an Apple Reference (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSMenuValidation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), but I couldn't use this reference because I don't understand how to disable it indeed.

```
- (BOOL)validateMenuItem:(NSMenuItem *)item {
    int row = [tableView selectedRow];
    if ([item action] == @selector(nextRecord) &&
        (row == [countryKeys indexOfObject:[countryKeys lastObject]])) {
        return NO;
    }
    if ([item action] == @selector(priorRecord) && row == 0) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

I thought I can use this function in this way:

```
on validateMenuItem_(myMenuItem)
    if myMenuItemIsEnabled = true then
        return true
    else
        return false
end validateMenuItem_
```

But this doesn't work (no response). How can I disable menu items?

Comment: I would first add a statement like say "in validateMenuItem" to see if this method iss being called, and also, simplifying the method by always returning false.  I'll get back to you with more when I have an answer (this is just a comment).

Answer (score 0):

After connecting the menu item to an IB property, use the following code to disable it:

```
set (myMenuItem's enabled) to false
```

Where myMenuItem is a property connected to the menu item you wish to disable. **You must make sure to uncheck the menu item's menu option called "Auto Enables Items".**